# cuando lanzo dos peticiones en angular un pisa la respuesta de la otra

Tags: angular

Tengo dos servicios
MedidorService y ConexionService  en cada uno genero una peticion HttpClient para obtener datos, por si solas funcionan perfecto pero cuando las ejecuto a las dos en paralelo hay ocaciones que la respuesta de una pisa la otra.

cuando son llamadas una a una debuelven los datos del backend de forma correcta. pero cuando llamo a las dos en paralelo en 1 de 10 veces falla y ambas respuesta me dan los datos de la ultima generada.

ej: si ejecuto MedidorService.matching y luego ConexionService.matching en 1/10 las dos respuesta son del  ConexionService.matching. pisa la respuesta del MedidorService.matching

**MedidorService**

```
matching(criteria :Criterial): Observable<{data: MedidorModel[],max_rows:number} | void> {
    var medidores: MedidorModel[] = [];
    var url = criteria.parseUrl(environment.server+"api/medidor/matching/full");

    return this.http.get<{data: MedidorModel[],max_rows:number} | void>(url).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        if (res.data != undefined) {
          res.data.forEach(  (medidor :MedidorModel)  => {

            medidores.push(new MedidorModel(
              medidor.id,
              medidor.numero,
              medidor.modelo,
              medidor.estado,
              medidor.concentrador,
              medidor.fecha_creacion,
              medidor.fecha_actualizacion
            ));

          });


          return {
            "data":medidores,
            "max_rows":res.max_rows
          };
        }

        return ;

      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        return throwError(err);
      })

    );
  }
```

**ConexionService**

```
matching(criteria :Criterial): Observable<{data: ConexionModel[],max_rows:number} | void> {
    var conexiones: ConexionModel[] = [];
    var url = criteria.parseUrl(environment.server+"api/cliente/conexion/matching/full");


    return this.http.get<{data: ConexionModel[],max_rows:number} | void>(url).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {

        if (res.data != undefined) {
          res.data.forEach(  (conexion :ConexionModel)  => {

            conexiones.push(new ConexionModel(
              conexion.id,
              conexion.cliente,
              conexion.numero,
              conexion.direccion,
              conexion.medidor,
              conexion.latitud,
              conexion.longitud,
              conexion.zona,
              conexion.fecha_creacion,
              conexion.fecha_actualizacion
            ));

          });


          return {
            "data":conexiones,
            "max_rows":res.max_rows
          };
        }

        return ;

      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        return throwError(err);
      })

    );
  }
```

Comment: Podrías utilizar las promesas, si sabes que siempre hay un orden, que tiene que ir primero cuando esta acabe , llamas a la siguiente, si no también te puede servir el forkjoin, pero tendría que ver donde se llaman y el orden, espero haber aclarado algo.

Comment: Puedes usar Pipes asi enlazar operadores para usar por ejemplo debounceTime

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar un `ForkJoin()`: realizas ambas peticiones, pero se esperan entre ellas y solo al tener respuesta de las dos te dispara el `Observable` que debes usar.

Para el ejemplo asumamos que creo dos métodos, uno para cada tipo de petición que tienes:

```
    this.medidorMatching(criteria);
    this.conexionMatching(criteria);
```

Ahora sí el ejemplo:

```
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs";
.
.
.
const medidor$ = this.medidorMatching(criteria);
const conexion$ = this.conexionMatching(criteria);


forkJoin([medidor$, conexion$]).subscribe((response: any[]) => {
   let medidor = response[0];
   let conexion = response[1];

   console.log('La respuesta de medidor = ', medidor);
   console.log('La respuesta de conexion = ', conexion); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Listo lo resolvi. el problema lo tenia en le backend.
**nodejs**.
Al generar la respuesta siempre utilizaba la variable result. al parecer nodejs al tener dos peticiones al mismo tiempo cargaba los datos de la ultima generada y devolvía.
**solucion** poner variables espesificas en cada caso.

**Codigo de fallo**

```
exports.matchingFull = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        var criterial = new Criterial(req.query.filters, req.query.orders, req.query.limit, req.query.offset)
         // misma varible
        result = await ZonaDao.matching(criterial); 
        result_max_rows = await ZonaDao.pagination(criterial);

        res.status(200).json({
            zonas: result ,
            max_rows: result_max_rows
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        if (e.code != undefined)
            res.status(e.code).json({ "error": e.message });
        else
            res.status(400).json({ "error": "a pasado algo inesperado" });
    }
}
```

**Codigo de solución**

```
exports.matchingFull = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        var criterial = new Criterial(req.query.filters, req.query.orders, req.query.limit, req.query.offset)
        //variable especifica
        var result_zona = await ZonaDao.matching(criterial); 
        var result_zona_max_rows = await ZonaDao.pagination(criterial);

        res.status(200).json({
            zonas: result_zona ,
            max_rows: result_zona_max_rows 
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        if (e.code != undefined)
            res.status(e.code).json({ "error": e.message });
        else
            res.status(400).json({ "error": "a pasado algo inesperado" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola RodolfoVizcay Para contestar a una respuesta utiliza los comentarios, y si quieres añadir mas inflo hazlo en la pregunta por medio del botón editar.